# Python AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute after using queue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a BFS solution to the 8 puzzle problem in python. However after I 'get()' a node from the queue and find the puzzle state inside that node it seems the puzzle object has turned into a list object without the method 'getMoves()'. I am wondering why it is not still a Puzzle object?

```
import collections
import queue

class Node:

    def __init__(self, Puzzle, last=None):
        self.puzzle = Puzzle
        self.last = last

    def getPuzzle(self):
        return self.puzzle

    def getLast(self):
        return self.last

class Puzzle:

    def __init__(self, startState, goalState):
        self.state = startState
        self.goal = goalState

    def getState():
        return self.state

    def getMoves(self):

        currentState = self.state

        possibleNewStates = []

        zeroPos = currentState.index(0)

        if zeroPos == 0:
            possibleNewStates.append(move(0,1))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(0,3))
        elif zeroPos == 1:
            possibleNewStates.append(move(1,0))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(1,2))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(1,4))
        elif zeroPos == 2:
            possibleNewStates.append(move(2,1))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(2,5))
        elif zeroPos == 3:
            possibleNewStates.append(move(3,0))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(3,4))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(3,6))
        elif zeroPos == 4:
            possibleNewStates.append(self.move(4,1))
            possibleNewStates.append(self.move(4,3))
            possibleNewStates.append(self.move(4,5))
            possibleNewStates.append(self.move(4,7))
        elif zeroPos == 5:
            possibleNewStates.append(move(5,2))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(5,4))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(5,8))
        elif zeroPos == 6:
            possibleNewStates.append(move(6,3))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(6,7))
        elif zeroPos == 7:
            possibleNewStates.append(move(7,4))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(7,6))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(7,8))
        else:
            possibleNewStates.append(move(8,5))
            possibleNewStates.append(move(8,7))

        return possibleNewStates

    def move(self, current, to):

        changeState = self.state

        save = changeState[to]
        changeState[to] = changeState[current]
        changeState[current] = save

        return changeState

    def printPuzzle(self):

        copyState = self.state
        print(copyState)
        '''
        for i in range(9):
            if i == 2 or i == 5:
                print((str)(copyState[i]))
            else:
                print((str)(copyState[i])+" ", end="")
            print()
        '''

    def isSolved(self):
        return self.state == self.goal

class Solver:

    def __init__(self, Puzzle):
        self.puzzle = Puzzle

    def solveBFS(self):
        puzzle = self.puzzle
        startNode = Node(puzzle)
        myQueue = queue.Queue(0)
        myQueue.put(startNode)
        myPuzzle = startNode.getPuzzle()
        print(myPuzzle.isSolved())
        while myQueue:
            currentNode = myQueue.get()
            currentPuzzle = currentNode.puzzle

            if currentPuzzle == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]:
                return currentNode

            nextMoves = currentPuzzle.getMoves() # << ERROR HERE
            for state in nextMoves:
                nextNode = Node(state, currentNode)
                myQueue.put(nextNode)

    startingState = [7,2,4,5,0,6,8,3,1]
    goalState = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    myPuzzle = Puzzle(startingState, goalState)
    mySolver = Solver(myPuzzle)
    goalNode = mySolver.solveBFS()
    goalPuzzle = goalNode.getPuzzle()
    goalPuzzle.printPuzzle()
```

Comment: Could you cut this down to a [mcve]? The process of doing so will likely help you to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Where is the `move()` **function** defined? In `Puzzle.getMoves()`, most code refers to a `move()` function, and some lines refer to the `self.moves()` method. It is that function that probably returns a list.

Comment: What does `currentNode.puzzle` return? It seems you expext _both_ a list and a `Puzzle` in the lines that follow. Also, don't use a class name as a variable/parameter name.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback! Very timely and very helpful. 
To jonrsharpe: I will try this, thank you
To Martijn Pieters: The move() function is not defined, each instance should be replaced with self.move()
To tobias_k: I was just trying different ways to get the Puzzle object stored in the current Node and I was confused as to why the if statement didn't receive a compiling error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in some cases, `state` must be a list when you create a new node:

```
nextMoves = currentPuzzle.getMoves()
for state in nextMoves:
    nextNode = Node(state, currentNode)
```

Here `state` must've been a list returned from the `Puzzle.getMoves()` list:

```
def getMoves(self):
    # ...

    possibleNewStates = []

    # append various objects to possibleNewStates.

    return possibleNewStates
```

In `getMoves()` you use *two* callables to produces new states:

```
possibleNewStates.append(move(0,1))
```

and

```
possibleNewStates.append(self.move(4,1))
```

`Puzzle.move()` produces a list; you do some swapping on `self.state` which you set to a list:

```
def move(self, current, to):
    changeState = self.state

    save = changeState[to]
    changeState[to] = changeState[current]
    changeState[current] = save

    return changeState
```

Note that this *mutates `self.state` in-place*; you did not create a copy of the value here.

`self.state` was set from the first argument to `Puzzle()`, which was a list:

```
startingState = [7,2,4,5,0,6,8,3,1]
goalState = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
myPuzzle = Puzzle(startingState, goalState)
```

so `self.move()` *returns a list, not a `Puzzle()` instance*.

You didn't share the definition of the `move()` global function; if this also produces a list then that's another cause of your `Node.puzzle` values becoming lists.

You probably want to correct all `move()` calls to use `self.move()`, and for `self.move()` to return a new `Puzzle()` instance. You'll need to create a *copy* of `self.state` list here too:

```
def move(self, current, to):
    changeState = self.state[:]  # create a copy    
    changeState[to], changeState[current] = changeState[current], changeState[to]
    return Puzzle(changeState, self.goal)
```

Answer (score 0):

All `move()` in `getMoves()` should be changed to `self.move()`. Otherwise you are working with an unbound Puzzle.

Comment: No, `move` is an un-specified global function. It is not the unbound `Puzzle.move` method.